# Raw SQL queries with EF code-first doesn't work

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm trying to display values from 2 tables (EF code-first) using SQL `JOIN` and `WHERE` clause.

```
Dim query = db.pt.SqlQuery("SELECT p.id, p.name, p.dob, pv.visitId, pv.vDate
                             FROM pt p 
                             JOIN pt_v pv ON p.id = pv.id
                             WHERE p.id like @p0 OR p.name like @p1", str1, str2).ToList()
```

I've tried an **alternate way**. Below is the code:

```
Dim id = New SqlParameter("@id", str1)
Dim name = New SqlParameter("@name", str2)
Dim query As String = "select p.id id, p.name name, p.dob dob, pv.visitId visitId, pv.vDate vDate
                       from pt p 
                       join pt_v pv on p.id = pv.id
                       where p.id like @id or p.name like @name"

Dim Result = db.Database.SqlQuery(Of PtLookupVM)(query, id, name).ToList()
```

PtLookupVM is my viewmodel class that has these:

```
Public Property id As String
Public Property name As String
Public Property dob As String
Public Property visitId As String
Public Property vDate As String
```

But the output result for both is zero rows.

This is the **sample data**:

```
Dim p As New List(Of pt) From {
        New pt() With {.id = 1, .name = "siti", .dob = "2011-11-17"},
        New pt() With {.id = 2, .name = "siti nur", .dob = "2011-12-17"}
}

Dim pv As New List(Of pt_v) From {
        New pt_v() With {.visitId = 1, .id = 1, .vDate = "2016-01-17"},
        New pt_v() With {.visitId = 2, .id = 1, .vDate = "2016-05-17"},
        New pt_v() With {.visitId = 3, .id = 2, .vDate = "2016-07-17"}
}


Dim pList As New List(Of PtLookupVM) From {
        New PtLookupVM() With {.id = 1, .name = "siti", .dob = "2011-11-17", .visitId = 1, .vDate = "2016-01-17"},
        New PtLookupVM() With {.id = 1, .name = "siti", .dob = "2011-11-17", .visitId = 2, .vDate = "2016-05-17"},
        New PtLookupVM() With {.id = 2, .name = "siti nur", .dob = "2011-12-17", .visitId = 3, .vDate = "2016-07-17"}
    }
```

What i'm trying to get is actually a list of people with the name "siti". But i don't want redundant values. So it should only display values as below:

This is my **expected output**:

```
Dim pList As New List(Of PtLookupVM) From {
        New PtLookupVM() With {.id = 1, .name = "siti", .dob = "2011-11-17", .visitId = 1, .vDate = "2016-01-17"},
        New PtLookupVM() With {.id = 2, .name = "siti nur", .dob = "2011-12-17", .visitId = 3, .vDate = "2016-07-17"}
}
```

Comment: Can you include sample data and your expected output?  Good on you for using a prepared statement.

Comment: I don't see the `id` column of table `pv` being defined, yet it is being used in the actual query.

Comment: What are the values of `str1` and `str2` that are supposed to match the **sample data**? If you are getting zero records with **alternate way**, then the filter does not match. If they do match, you should be getting what you've shown in `pList` variable. So at the end, what really are you getting?

Comment: @IvanStoev str1 is supposed to be value of id, and str2 is value of name. The thing is when i run the the query, the query returns count=0 at the for each breakpoint for the query. That means that it doesn't find any match right?

Comment: @Nurul Right. My point was to check the **values** of `str1` and `str2` that you pass.

Comment: @IvanStoev i think it showed correctly &#64;str1 for str1 and &#64;str2 for str2. And when i expand str1, the ParameterName = "&#64;str1", the SqlValue = {2}. 2 is what i entered for str1, and also the same thing for str2 i entered siti. sorry i had to put the html code for 'at' symbol because it coincides with the mention other username function in SO

Comment: @IvanStoev i just realized that the Results = Nothing

Comment: Here is the point. The SQL contains `p.name like @name` criteria. Let say `str2 = "siti"`. In order to match both "siti" and "siti nur", you need to use willcard, something like `Dim name = New SqlParameter("@name", "%" & str2 & "%")`

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks so much! U saved my day!! If you would like to do an answer below, i could upvote and mark yours as answer.

Comment: @Nurul You are welcome, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let take the query with named parameters (what you call the alternate way). The criteria used in `WHERE` clause referring to these parameters are

```
p.id like @id
```

and

```
p.name like @name
```

As you can see, there are no placeholders used, so if you don't supply them thru parameters, the `LIKE` will simply work as `=`, thus will not match what do you expect when for instance `str2` contains "sity".

To match the string regardless of the position inside the target field, you should surround the user value with "%":

```
Dim id = New SqlParameter("@id", "%" & str1 & "%")
Dim name = New SqlParameter("@name", "%" & str2 & "%")
```

or if you prefer the first variant with implicit parameters:

```
Dim query = db.pt.SqlQuery("SELECT p.id, p.name, p.dob, pv.visitId, pv.vDate
                             FROM pt p 
                             JOIN pt_v pv ON p.id = pv.id
                             WHERE p.id like @p0 OR p.name like @p1", "%" & str1 & "%", "%" & str2 & "%").ToList()
```